# What will IE9 do if it encounters X-UA-Compatible header that says to emulate IE10?

Tags: internet-explorer, internet-explorer-9, internet-explorer-10, internet-explorer-11, x-ua-compatible

We want IE11 to emulate IE10 so we're going to add a X-UA-Compatible directive to **IE=EmulateIE10**.  But if our server is hit by IE9, how will IE9 interpret that directive?

Comment: The directive is interpreted clientside, by the browser. See: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj676915%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: @analytalica his question does not imply misunderstanding that; at least I interpretted to mean, if IE 9 hits his server (which is returning the X-UA-Compatilbe directive), how will the browser interpet that.

Comment: Yes, sorry, my question was how will IE9 interpret a directive to emulate IE10.  Edited my question for clarity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj676915%28v=vs.85%29.aspx, IE9 will operate in IE9 Standards mode if it sees the X-UA-Compatable set to IE10)

> ("If the browser supports the header, but not any of the specified
>   document modes, it will use the highest supported document mode to
>   display the webpage.")

You can check this (if you have IE 9 lying around, which thankfully I do not) by going to the page and bringing up developer tools to see what mode it was set to and why (well, assuming developer tools in IE 9 worked the same way as it does with 10+)

Comment: An important subtlety should be mentioned: In IE10, quirks mode is interoperable unless you specifically select IE5 as a document mode.  When using an "emulate" document mode, this could have a dramatic impact between the two version.  When viewed with IE10, a quirks mode page defaults to [interoperable quirks mode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh869300(v=vs.85).aspx) while IE9 defaults to IE5 mode.
So the answer for the OP is "It depends on the <!doctype>.  If there's no <!doctype>, then you'll get very different experiences."